# Laravel include relationships with model after update

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using a role package which stores hasMany relational data in my database. So there is a `users` table and a `user_roles` table with foreign keys...etc...

I am updating the model using the following code:

```
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->update(request()->all());
    $user->syncRoles(request()->input('roles', []));
```

Is there any way I can keep a reference of the `roles` on the `$user` variable so they can be used after these lines of code run?

I'm asking because I'm using a logging system after the fact like so:

```
    activity()->on($user)->by(auth()->user())->withProperties([
        'user' => $user,
        'roles' => request()->input('roles'),
    ])->log('Updated User');
```

Which I would like to condense to just:

```
    activity()->on($user)->by(auth()->user())->withProperties($user)->log('Updated User');
```

Comment: not sure what you mean by keeping them in the same variable.

Comment: You will need to refresh the model. Look at the `fresh()` function on the Eloquent model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to refresh the model data from the database. E.g.

```
$user = $user->fresh('roles');
```

Answer (score 0):

For example using lazy loading:

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
$roles = $user->roles;
```

and on your `User` Model you would create a `HasMany` relationship to roles table.

Eager loading:

```
$user = User::with('roles')->findOrFail($id);
```

Comment: I updated OP.....is it possible to keep them both within the same variable?

Answer (score 0):

Add the relationship in your User.php model :

```
public function roles(){
    return $this->hasMany(Role::class);
}
```

Now simply call it in your code to get the roles like so:

```
$aUser = User::with('roles')->find($id);
$roles = $aUser->roles;
```